# If you include a .pri, shouldn't that .pri's include path affect your #includes?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

If I `include(someOtherProject.pri)` in my `.pro`, and that other project file (.pri) has `INCLUDEPATH += .` in it, then shouldn't my files in my .pro find those headers when I `#include` them? I cleaned and ran qmake on everything, regenerated the .pri file by simply copying the .pro from that other project and renaming it with the .pri extension, but when I `#include` a file from that other project, compiler says it cannot find it.

I wouldn't expect that I must *also* edit the `INCLUDEPATH` of my working .pro file if I am already using `include(someOtherProject.pri)` -- that would make the point of using `include(someOtherProject.pri)` unnecessary altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to have `INCLUDE PATH += $$PWD/` in the .pri instead, as this will expand out to the proper hard-coded path no matter where it is included.